# Frame for "Label" will be different at run time - XCODE 8 IOS

Tags: swift, xcode8

I created an ios app with a scroll view that works with views[paging enabled]. On each page, everything is on the edge of the screen -  the center is on the right edge of the screen, where it is supposed to be on the center.

Xcode(8) gives me a warning:

> 'Frame for "e.g Label" will be different at run time'

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh all frames in the view controller.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Go to your main.storyboard and than click on your view controller. you'll see 5 little buttons on the bottom of your xcode window. Click on the most right one and than you'll get a lot of options. I think the right option is called "update frames", but I'm not very sure about that.

Comment: Did not work for me. The main.storyboard just has a scroll view - which goes though all the other .xib files by the way.